# Interpret a date from a string of digits

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, error-handling

I developed a function that, from a given sequence of digits, extracts the date and reformat it.
This is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt


def format_dates(field):
    n = len(field)
    match = False
    i = 0
    while match is False:
        try:
            # Take the last four digits
            year = int(field[-4 - i:n - i])
        except ValueError:
            return ''

        # Check if this year is between today's year +/- (15, 100)
        if (1919 <= year <= 2019):
            # Check if there are other 4 digits before these 4 ones
            if (len(field[-8 - i:n - i]) == 8):
                try:
                    f_date = dt.strptime(field[-8 - i:n - i],
                                         '%d%m%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                    match = True
                    return f_date
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            else:
                return ''
        i += 1
```

**Explanation:**
This function:

- Takes a sequence of digits as input.
- extracts the last four digits from that sequence.
- Checks if the extracted four digits are between 2019 and 1919, if not, it breaks.
- If yes, it checks if there are more 4 digits before the previously extracted ones, if not it breaks.
- If yes, it tries to format the whole 8 digits.
- If there is a ValueError exception, it passes (ValueError, means there are 8 digits, the last four of them represent a correct year, but the fist four digits are wrong. So it passes to increment i + 1 to add a the next digits in the front and remove the last digit in the processed sequence).

**Example:**

*input: '1303201946'*

1. Iteration 1:

   - i = 0, match = False
   - year = 1946
   - test 1 (year between 2019 and 1919): passes.
   - test2 (there are 4 other digits before 1946, which are 0320): passes.
   - format the whole 8 digits: ValueError exception, so i = i+1 and pass to the next iteration.
2. Iteration 2:

   - i = 1, match = False
   - year = 0194
   - test 1 (year between 2019 and 1919): fails, so i = i + 1 and pass to the next iteration.
3. Iteration 3:

   - i = 2, match = False
   - year = 2019
   - test 1: passes
   - test 2: passes
   - format the whole 8 digits (13032019): 13/03/2019 (No ValueError exception) passes
   - match = True, return the formatted date, break from the while loop.

This function works fine, but the way it handles the errors seems ugly. Also I believe it is not optimized (same exceptions are repeated, a lot of returns and the code does not seem elegant).
How to reformat the code and make it more optimized?

Comment: This gives a `NameError: name 'sub_field' is not defined`

Comment: @MaartenFabré, sorry I fixed it, it should be field instead of sub_field

Comment: @MaartenFabré, There was some errors in the code, I fixed them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Exception

If your algorithm cannot find a date, it is easier to raise an Exception than to return `''`. Returning sentinel values instead of exceptions can lead to unexpected behaviour if the user of this function does not test for this sentinel value.

## comments

Comments should explain why you did something, not how. `# Take the last four digits` tells you nothing more than the code itself. I would rather comment at `field[-4 - i:n - i]` why you did `n - i` instead of just `-i`.

## nesting

Instead of nesting a number of if-clauses, it can be better to test the negative of the condition, and `continue`, so the rest of the code is less nested.

## match

Don't test `condition is True`. Just do `condition`. In Python a lot of values can act as `True` or `False` in tests.

Your `match` is never used anyway; the moment you set it to `True`, you also return the result, so a `while True:` would have sufficed here.

## `field`

This is a very unclear variable name. This method excepts a date in string format, so why not call the argument like that?

## Return type

Your code does 2 things now. It looks for a date in the string, and converts that date to another format. It would be better to separate those 2 things, and return a `datetime.datetime` instead, and let the caller of this method worry about formatting that correctly.

## `while True`

You use a `while True`-loop, with an incrementing counter. A better way to do this would be to either use `for i in range(...)` or using `itertools.count`: `for i in itertools.count()`. In this case you know there will be no more than `len(field) - 7` iterations, so you might as well use that.

## Revert the algorithm

You explicitly test whether the substring is 8 characters long, and then if it is in the right format. By changing the `while True` to the `for`-loop, you know the substring will be 8 characters long. Then it makes sense to first try to convert it to a `datetime`, and then check whether the year is correct:

```
def format_dates2(date_string):
    n = len(date_string)
    for i in range(n - 7):
        sub_string = date_string[-(8 + i) : n - i]
        # not just -i because that fails at i==0
        try:
            date = dt.strptime(sub_string, "%d%m%Y")
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if not (1919 <= date.year <= 2019):
            continue
        return date
    raise ValueError("Date not in the correct format")
```